# List Occurence wise read c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, c#-4.0

I have Class Like this

```
  public  class RoomDetails
  {
     public int RoomIndexID {get;set;} --(This is No of Rooms)
     public int roomcategoryID {get;set;} -- (This is No of Category that room have)
     public decimal roomPrice{get;set;}
     public string roomCategory{get;set;}
  }
```

So i have RoomDetails List like this(data)

- 1,1,200,Single Bed
- 2,1,250,Double Bed
- 2,2,400,Double Bed with Extra View
- 2,4,530,Tripple Bed
- 3,1,530,Tripple Bed
- 3,2,600,Triple Large Bed

so i want to read this list following procedure.

- 1,1,200,Single Bed
- 2,1,250,Double Bed
- 3,1,530,Tripple Bed

---

- 1,1,200,Single Bed
- 2,1,250,Double Bed
- 3,2,600,Triple Large Bed

---

- 1,1,200,Single Bed
- 2,2,400,Double Bed with Extra View
- 3,1,530,Tripple Bed

---

- 1,1,200,Single Bed
- 2,2,400,Double Bed with Extra View
- 3,2,600,Triple Large Bed

---

- 1,1,200,Single Bed
- 2,4,530,Tripple Bed
- 3,1,530,Tripple Bed

---

- 1,1,200,Single Bed
- 2,4,530,Tripple Bed
- 3,2,600,Triple Large Bed

please ask if you have any problem regrading my question.

This is example

my data list is like this

- Room A  -- A1
- Room B  -- B1 , B2 , B3
- Room C  -- C1 , C2

(Actually A ,B, C means RoomIndexID 's and A1,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2 is roomcategoryID 's)
so I want to read it like this.

- A1,B1,C1
- A1,B1,C2
- A1,B2,C1
- A1,B2,C2
- A1,B3,C1
- A1,B3,C2

Comment: By what do you want to group it? I don't see any connection in any of the listing

Comment: There  is RoomIndexID.1,2,3 like wise. and there is roomcategoryID.
lets say first room 1,1,200,Single Bed if same room index have another room then it would be like 1,2,200,Single Bed

I dont want to group.i want some mecanism of read this list RoomIndexID and roomcategoryID based.i ll add sample example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "LINQy" solution, it will be a little complicated. Please note that it is LINQ to object, so you will need to call `.ToList()` first if you have `IQueryable` (for example from EntityFramework).

```
var total = list.GroupBy(x=>x.RoomIndexID)
    .Select(x=>x.Count())
    .Aggregate(1, (s,d)=>s*d);

var counts = list.GroupBy(x => x.RoomIndexID)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

var nums = list.GroupBy(x => x.RoomIndexID)
    .Select(x => x.Select((p, i) => new {i, p}))
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, total)
    .Select(x =>
        nums.Where(y => {               
            var c = counts[y.p.RoomIndexID];
            var p = counts
                      .Where(z => z.Key > y.p.RoomIndexID)
                      .Aggregate(1, (s,d)=>s*d.Value);

            return y.i == x/p%c;
        })
        .Select(y => y.p)
    );
```

Demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/udf6VA

Comment: thanks for the help.this code did the job perfectly...
but its too complex.could you please give me some explanation about this code?

Answer (score 0):

A lot simpler, something like this would do:

```
var groups = list // your input
    .GroupBy(x => x.RoomIndexID)
    .Select(x => x.ToList())
    .ToList();

var result = groups.Skip(1).Aggregate(
    groups.Take(1),
    (x, y) => x.SelectMany(z => y, (a, b) => a.Concat(new[] { b }).ToList()));
```

Basically the idea is to first `GroupBy` room index so that you get inner sequences of same type, then perform cross joins among those sequences (`SelectMany` would be fine for it), and lastly `Aggregate` the joined results. These three steps should do fine. The steps involved could be clearer with the following imperative style example:

```
var groups = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.RoomIndexID)
    .Select(x => x.ToList());

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<RoomDetails>> result = null;
foreach (var item in groups)
{
    if (result == null)
        result = new[] { item };
    else
        result = result.SelectMany(x => item, (x, y) => x.Concat(new[] { y }));
}
```

This thing could have been done in one step had we had a proper overload for `Aggregate` which takes a `Func` of first item in the sequence as the seed.

```
// Say you have:
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TAccumulate> seeder,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> func)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    if (func == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(func));

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Empty sequence.");

        TAccumulate result = seeder(iterator.Current);
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            result = func(result, iterator.Current);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

// Then you could do: 
var result = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.RoomIndexID)
    .Select(x => x.ToList())
    .Aggregate(
        x => Enumerable.Repeat(x, 1),
        (x, y) => x.SelectMany(z => y, (a, b) => a.Concat(new[] { b }).ToList()));
```

This whole thing looks complicated because of some of the missing pieces either in the framework or the language. Ideally (and in many functional languages I assume) you should be able to do:

```
var result = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.RoomIndexID)
    .Aggregate(x => x.Yield(), (x, y) => x.SelectMany(z => y, (a, b) => a.Append(b)));
```